# Which is faster: != or <

Tags: optimization

Which of the following is faster?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
```

I'm wondering because I don't understand hardware and thus don't understand how a computer looks at `<` versus `!=`.

Comment: It's not just about the hardware.  There are too many factors.  It's probably best to try to measure the performance yourself.  Also consider the effect of bugs.  Both of these constructs can loop forever, if you have bugs in your code.  Which type of bug is easier to avoid, easier to spot and easier to fix?

Comment: You dont need this level of performance. You should use the first for readibility and because the second one will not work if i > n

Comment: a) What language, compiler, architecture, etc are you talking about? b) The difference is going to be so small that you should never care.

Comment: I assume from the syntax this is `C++` question.

Comment: If `n==-1` the top loop executes zero times, but the bottom one loops billions of times.  So I guess the top one is, statistically speaking, over all values of `n`, faster! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For primitive types, both operations take the exact same amount of time since both are actually determined regardless of which you ask for.

In short, whenever you make a basic comparison, `<` `<=` `>` `>=` `==` or `!=`, one side of the operator is subtracted from the other. The result of the subtraction is then used to set a number of flags, the most important of which are `Z` (zero), `N` (negative), and `O` (overflow). Based on the names, you should be able to figure out what each flag represents. Ex: if the result of subtraction is zero, than the `Z` flag is set. Thus, whether you ask for `<=` or `!=`, all the processor is doing is checking the flags which have all been set appropriately as a result of the initial subtraction.

Theoretically, `<=` should take *slightly* longer since two flags (Z and N) must be checked instead of one (`=` just cares about Z). But this happens on such a low level that the results are most likely negligible even on a microsecond scale.

If you're really interested, read up on [processor status registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_register).

For non-primitive types, i.e. classes, it depends on the implementation of the relational operators.

Answer (score 0):

These compile to exactly the same number of machine instructions - both Jump on Equality and Jump if Less are single Assembly instructions. You can read about these instructions here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow#Jump_on_Equality

Answer (score 0):

The comparisons `<` and `!=` both take a single instruction, however the values of the two operands need to be loaded into the registers first.

For primitive data types such as `int`, `bool`, etc, each comparison will take 3 CPU instructions. For other data types it will take at least 3 instructions but maybe more.

It can also depend on the compiler and the compile-time optimisations used.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the value of `i` in the loop body to something greater than `n` (perhaps you need to increment `i` twice if a specific condition is met, and this could happen on the last iteration), or change `n` to something less than `i`, then the second version (with `!=`) the loop will not terminate.

If you want to iterate `n` times, then the first version (with `<`) is a bit safer.

It's easier to prove the first version will terminate.

(though unlikely, if you literally want the loop to continue iterating if `n == i` is skipped, then use the second version obviously)