# Whether to check == equals or != not equals in if else block

Tags: java, performance, optimization

I have a question on performance (if at all it impacts) on two different style of equals comparision:

```
if(obj!=null)
{
    //perform some operation set 1
}
else
{
        //do operation set 2
}
```

vs

```
if(obj==null)
{
    //do operation set 2
}
else
{
        //perform some operation set 1
}
```

In first case, I read somewhere that its double assignment but can't recall now. Are both the case same as far as performance/assignment is considered?

**Edit**

See PMD rule e.g [Link1](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/xref/net/sourceforge/pmd/rules/design/ConfusingTernary.html) or [Link 2](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/design.html)(where it talks of one style being better in terms of readability at least, search for heading ConfusingTernary)

Comment: This seems to be a reasonable question. Why so many downvotes?

Comment: First one is better since Object won't be null in many cases if coding was done right

Comment: your answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462898/which-is-faster-or

Comment: Preference should also be decided based on your flow of control. Suppose if an object is null then return null otherwise proceed as normal. In such case i would prefer checking ==null .

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which scenario is going to occur more frequent in your case. Always keep the more frequect scenario as first block.

Let say I have to test if A > 10 or not , then I will see my business requirment if possibility of A being greater 10 is more that I keep it as first block.

Most of the cases, null values are very less frequest so one should have it as second block .

```
  if(obj!=null){
   //perform some operation set 1
  }else{
   //do operation set 2
  }
```

Because what you doing in one case is :-

```
  check cond 1 > if true > execute
```

or

```
  check cond 1 > if false > check 2 > if true > execute
```

So if you know cond 1 is going to be true in most cases , then opt this .

Comment: I don't think it needs a second check, it just executes the second part if the answer is a false. Because it is just an else not an else if

Comment: I think that is the best explanation so far and in sync with Code Optimiser tools explanation http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/design.html (Heading ConfusingTernary)

Answer (score 1):

From the performance point of view both are the same. JIT compiler is free to rearrange these branches if it discovers that swapping them may improve the performance. In source code use the order which improves readability of your source and leave the performance issues to the JIT compiler. It knows better.

Answer (score 0):

> No. There is no performance impact.

It is just like asking do you have apples?

```
If yes then make apple milk shake else makes orange juice.
```

Now the other way around.

Do you have oranges?

```
If it is a yes make orange juice or a apple milk shake.
```

Both are the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's more of coding style. Here's a post which might be what you are looking for   [..link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement)

Comment: Umm that's not the right link. This question is a bit different from that.